ScopedContextData is not available in ObjectType resolver in Hot Chocolate GraphQL
In my C# .NET GraphQL HotChocolate setup, I have ObjectA and ObjectB, where ObjectB serves as a property of ObjectA. To handle resolving data for ObjectA, I've defined a resolver. Within this resolver, I've implemented scoped state management using HotChocolate's capabilities.
Here's how I've set the scoped state:
descriptor.Field(c => c.itemId).Use(next => async ctx =>
{
    await next(ctx);
    ctx.SetScopedState("itemId", ctx.Result);
    ctx.SetLocalState("itemId", ctx.Result);
    ctx.SetGlobalState("itemId", ctx.Result);
});

This piece of code effectively retrieves the result and sets it as scoped, local, and global state, ensuring its availability for subsequent operations within the resolver and beyond.
However, when attempting to access this scoped state within the resolver for ObjectB, I encountered an issue. Despite setting the state for itemId at different scopes, it appears that only the global state is accessible within ObjectB's resolver:
var idScope = ctx.GetScopedState<object>("itemId");
var idGlobal = ctx.GetGlobalState<object>("itemId");
var idLocale = ctx.GetLocalState<object>("itemId");

only idGlobal yields the expected value, indicating that the scoped and local states are not accessible as intended within ObjectB's resolver. This observation prompts further investigation into HotChocolate's scoped state handling to ensure consistent data access across resolvers.
